# Selenium can't locate elements inside HTML doc within another HTML doc

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, iframe, webdriver

I don't know what's exactly the thing that Amazon opens when you click the "buy now" button, I tryed to search on internet but couldn't find a clear answer. It could be a pop-up or an iframe, but they call it "popover" in their source code, which I have no clue what it is.

The point is, once you open this "popover", Selenium is unable to parse any part of that frame since it's a standalone separate HTML doc. I'm not sure if it's an iframe as I've never seen an iframe like that, so any guide I serached online about how to switch context using an Handler to an iframe doesn't work here. I couldn't find an ID, name, or anything significant to allow Selenium to parse the frame.

[image showing the "popover"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76VK0.jpg)

If anyone has any clue how this HTML element is actually called and how to allow Selenium to parse it, please let me know, thanks.

Comment: You can't right click on it and inspect element?

Comment: I can inspect the element.

Comment: Can you access the xpath of the element after inspecting? What are you trying to do after the element pop up?

Answer (score 0):

I checked HTML of the page and here are my findings:

1. 'Close' button is **not** in iFrame
2. Popup content itself is in iframe

See screenshot below:
[image]

What does it mean for you:

1. In order to click on the button 'Close' (e.g. by css selector `button[class*='a-button-close']`) you do not need to switch to any frames. If you are failing to click on the button - I would assume that you are missing selenium wait. There is a small delay after you clicking on "Buy Now" button and before popup actually loads - you need to explicitly wait for it to load. See https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html for more details on selenium waits. I would recommend using `visibility_of_element_located` or `visibility_of` to wait for popup/button to appear (load) in your case.
2. If you did any operations in the popup itself (e.g. if you clicked on some links inside of it) - you most likely switched to the context of the iFrame with `driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)`. In this case - you need to switch back to main context with `driver.switch_to.default_content()` in order to click on the 'Close' button (since it is outside of iframe).
3. I highly recommend learning runtime evaluate technique - it will save you hours on debugging your applications - see https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/guide/tips/evaluate-expression/

P.S. next time when asking question - please post your code (at least on high level) - it will help with localizing issue.

Comment: Thank a you a lot for your very detailed answer. Can I ask you why my code doesn't work? `driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id('turbo-checkout-frame'))` It gives me "NoSuchFrameException: Message: no such frame: element is not a frame"

Comment: So, the iframe is visibile only when you inspect it, but not if you do "view page source", so maybe that's why Selenium can't switch context.

Comment: @cholmugod
I think I've got exact reason why it does not work for you.
```#turbo-checkout-frame``` - is id for DIV which wraps iframe.
And because it is a DIV - selenium says you can't switch to it.
In order to switch to iframe - you need to use it's ID: ```iframe id="turbo-checkout-iframe"```
Try with ```driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id('turbo-checkout-iframe'))``` - and it will work.

Comment: It won't work like that because the source code of the page doesn't follow HTML DOM rules: both the div and iframe got the same ID (which is forbidden), so selenium picks the first one, which is the div. I made it work using either css selector or xpath, telling selenium to look for <iframe> that has id=turbo-checkout-iframe